# OWASP Zap Exclude in Proxy everything but given URL

Tags: regex, filter, proxy, zap

My question is pretty straightforward I want to exclude from proxy everything but this 2 URLS, just want to see the traffic of 1 site.

`http://www.timetosa.com` and `https://www.timetosa.com`

This is the REG I have inserted in the Exclude from Proxy section without success:

```
\Q!(http?://www.timetosa.com/)\E.*
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came across this exact problem and this is the Regex that worked for me:

```
^(?:(?!http:\/\/localhost:3000).*).$
```

Where http://localhost:3000 is the only address I wanted included.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
\Qhttp?://www.timetosa.com\E.*
```

or

```
\Qhttp://www.timetosa.com\E.*
```

Comment: But where¿? by doing that I include only timetosa, but I need to exclude eveything that is not timetosa, because as far as I know there is a: only include

Comment: In session properties there is a option called Exclude from proxy

Answer (score 0):

Simply put it as `\Qhttp\Es?\Q://www.timetosa.com/\E.*`.